Download fails multiple
download of ubuntu tries to open with VLC. I am not experienced with operating systems install and have not tried to do anything like that since 20yrs ago. The downloads are failing according to the download meter on the browser (firefox) and then I locate the download in the downloads folder and it opens with VLC and gives no option to use any installer program. It offers to let me download programs from the windows store. 64bit medion computer bought in 2017 from aldi on a whim. I am having trouble finding simple help to just download and save onto a usb stick for install at a later time. Thanks for any replies.

You may find this helpful: What program do I use to open the .iso file I download to use for installing ubuntu?

Pls edit your question, add Ubuntu version and also which programs you are trying to download, installing programs is different than installing in windows.

Does this answer your question? What is the proper way of creating installation media from Ubuntu iso?
